# Xamarin.Android desperately need to update but can't due to external storage

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mediastore, scoped-storage

So my company's app desperately needs to be updated. However, I've always avoided targeting SDK 30 for not having to deal with the whole 'getting rejected due to MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'.

FYI: I'm very poor at programming and lave little knowledge especially in this subject with things not coding related..

The only thing, literally the only thing this app does is retreive a base64 pdf, convert it, save it to the device, and open it.
I cannot find a simple way/explanation anywhere to work around this. My app needs to be updated, but I'm forced to use SDK30 which google will reject due to this whole storage policy thing..

This is how we work with PDF's in our code:

```
private async void PDFDrawer(int pos)
    {
      UI ui = new UI(this);
      ui.ShowProgressDialog("", "Laden");
      Console.WriteLine(invoices[pos].Obj["InvoiceID"].ToString());

      //get PDF based on list selection
      JsonValue json = await getPDFTask(invoices[pos].Obj["InvoiceID"].ToString());
      var PDFResults = json["InvoicePDFResponse_InvoicePDF"];
      var pdf = (string)PDFResults[0]["PDFString"];
      byte[] pdfAsBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(pdf);

      var externalStorageState = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageState;

      String path = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "/AppName";
      Console.WriteLine("pad: " + path);
      if (!Directory.Exists(path))
      {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
      }

      String file_path = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "/AppName";
      Java.IO.File dir = new Java.IO.File(file_path);
      if (!dir.Exists())
      {
        var b = dir.Mkdir();
      }

      try
      {
        String noMediaPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "/AppName/.nomedia";
        if (!File.Exists(noMediaPath))
        {
          File.CreateText(noMediaPath);
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Xamarin.Insights.Report(ex);
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
      }

      var externalPath = Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir("AppName").AbsolutePath + "/" + "invoice.pdf";
      File.WriteAllBytes(externalPath, pdfAsBytes);

      //open pdf file on device
      OpenFile(externalPath);

      ui.HideProgressDialog();
    }
```

In my AndroidManifest I have:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <protected-broadcast android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="AppName" android:icon="@mipmap/logoIconWhite" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
        <provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
```

Please if anyone can help me out.. Xamarin native is old, it sucks, but I need to get an update trough without this headdace inducing problem and miles-long documentation on the subject from Google for just simply downloading and opening a pdf...

EDIT:
After @Cheesebaron 's suggestion to remove MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, it still gets refused.. see image:
[Email from Google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IlRy.png)

EDIT:
Now the app was finally accepted, however, the app now crashed on Android 11 devices..

Comment: What do you need the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission for? This one is for system apps only. READ/WRITE external storage should be enough for you. Just remember to request runtime permission for it.

Comment: @Cheesebaron Is that really it? just getting rid of the permission? okay haha. Would you have any lead as to where I would ask for runtime permission? Or do you mean the standard acces to files popup from the OS?

Comment: Yep, the standard permission pop up. You could use Xamarin.Essentials.Permissions for that, super easy to set up if you haven't used it before.

Comment: @Cheesebaron Alright thanks. But the app already asks this by default, so I'd imagine I don't have to implement it? Otherwise I'll look into it. I have it in review now at the play store, fingers crossed.

Comment: @Cheesebaron Please see update in the question. It still got rejected, but from what I can see not because I didn't implement runtime permission manually i think? It's so vague.. What should I do?

Comment: that sounds like they think you still have MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE enabled

Comment: @Jason Yeah inoticed my 'Properties' still having the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE checkbox marked even tough I removed the line from my manifest.. Will now try to re-upload the app on the play-store again fingers crossed

Comment: Is there still an error message?

Comment: @Wen xu Li The app is now accepted in the play-store, however, as I feared, Android 11 devices cannot open the PDF files.. the app crashes

Comment: For new problems, you can post a new problem and describe the detailed error message.

Comment: @JustinvanBrecht We are also facing this exact issue. How did you overcome MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE  issue. We also have removed it from the manifest and the permission list. But still getting rejected. Thank you